# Lyx: change screen fonts for "section" and "part" environments

Tags: lyx

Default screen fonts for Part and Section are the same, which makes them confusing to use. Is there a way to change them?

Answer (score 2):

In the layouts folder in LyX' application directory, you will find a file called `article.layout`, which defines how document elements should appear in LyX. Most are inherited from `stdclass.inc`, but the layout for `Part` and `Part*` are defined there, as follows:

```
Style Part
    Align                 Left
    AlignPossible         Left
    TopSep                2
    BottomSep             1.5
    Font
      Size                Larger
    EndFont
End


Style Part*
    Align                 Left
    AlignPossible         Left
    TopSep                2
    BottomSep             1.5
    Font
      Size                Larger
    EndFont
End
```

These types of definitions can be added to the *Local layout* in the Document settings. There is also a button there to save whatever you add as Document defaults. Other valid values for the `Size` parameter is `Largest` and `Huge`. I do not know all the possible things one can put here, but for example changing the `Font` part in the above to

```
Font
  Size              Huge
  Color             blue
EndFont
```

and adding it to Document --> Settings --> Local layout will set parts in a larger font, and blue colour.

Comment: A good reference is Help > Customization